# Using two base addresses in Refit + cert x509

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, flurl, refit

Right now I am using the IHttpClientFactory interface and it works perfect. Now I need to use the Refit library. Is this possible to do?

i am doing this right now:

DI:

```
.AddHttpClient(
    "name_client",
    c =>
    {
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0");
    }
)
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    // The web site needs login with certificate digital from path
    CookieContainer? cookieContainer = new();
    HttpClientHandler? handler =
        new() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(
        DigitalCert.GetCert(context.Configuration)
    );
    return handler;
});
```

LOGIN:

```
public async Task Connect(string url)
{
    HttpClient httpclient = clientFactory.CreateClient(clientName);
    var res = await httpclient!.GetAsync(
        Path.Combine(
            string.Format(
                "https://serverlogin.com/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi?reference={0}",
                url // https://server2.com/
            )
        )
    );
}
```

GETDATA:

```
public async Task GetInfo(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    message.RequestUri = new Uri("https://server2.com/cve_cgi/api/users/");
    HttpClient httpclient = clientFactory.CreateClient(clientName);
    HttpResponseMessage? res = await httpclient!.SendAsync(message);
}
```

I'm using refit like this:

DI:

```
services
    .AddRefitClient<IInterfaceRefit>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
    {
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0");
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://serverlogin.com");
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {        
        // get cert
    });
```

```
public interface IInterfaceRefit
 {
     [Get("/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi")]
     Task Connect(string reference);

     [Get("/cvc_cgi/dte/rf_reobtencion2_folios/")]
     Task<string> GetInfo(
         [Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string, object> data
     );   
 }
```

My problem with this approach is the change of base address. How could doing well?
I have tried to change the base address in runtime with DelegatingHandler, but that approach doesn't work because the login was done to another endpoint.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test the solution now, but I suspect you can use `public static IHttpClientBuilder AddRefitClient(this IServiceCollection services, Type refitInterfaceType, RefitSettings? settings = null)` to specify two different interfaces derived from `IInterfaceRefit` and use the appropriate sub-interface when requesting the concrete singleton from DI. Each can be configured separately and the sub-interface serves just to differentiate the two.

Comment: @EricJ. In the native approach it works very well, I am calling one baseaddres for login and another for queries and in each method a new instance of the httpclient is created with a different baseaddress; it's like they share the same connection. However, when I use the new library, both methods work separately, so it is as if I were not logged in.

Comment: My guess is, the login is returning a cookie (likely representing a JWT token) that you will have to submit on every subsequent access attempt to the service. Check the response headers by manually logging into the service in your browser and using the network tab of the browser dev tools. If that's the case, you'll need to capture the cookie and add it to every subsequent request. Note that JWT tokens expire, so your flow could be to hit the service endpoint and, when that returns authentication failure, log in to get a new JWT, then retry the connection.

Comment: @EricJ. this is the first response: https://prnt.sc/I8Uk1d5sg60m There must be a way to be able to reuse that same client in the second request. Why does it work with the native form and not with Refit?

Comment: Have a look at this example for getting the auth token via code. Do some reasearch to see how to add that token to subsequent requests https://github.com/renatogroffe/DotNetCore2.2_Refit-JWT/blob/master/CargaProdutos/Program.cs